# Condense IF Statement As Seems Over Kill

Tags: javascript, jquery

New To `JQuery`, i have the following code which i think is a bit over kill as all i'm trying to do i match a returned value to a selection of buttons and add/remove a `class`.

**HTML for days of the week buttons**

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="selectWeekdaysSection">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4">
            <button id="mon" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Mon">Mon</button>
            <button id="tue" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Tue">Tue</button>
            <button id="wed" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Wed">Wed</button>
            <button id="thur" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Thur">Thur</button>
            <button id="fri" name="weekdaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Fri">Fri</button>
            <button id="sat" name="weekenddaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Sat">Sat</button>
            <button id="sun" name="weekenddaysbutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Sun">Sun</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gives this on the site

[image]

DataTable data

[image]

When i do call and get data back from my `DataTable` it pre-selects the days from the `JSON`.  I have all this working but as i said seems over kill to have to keep repeating the `IF` just for a different button especially when i have to do this for days '01 - 31'

**Jquery**

```
var selectedDays = modifyRecordData.selectedDays;
var splitSelectedDays = selectedDays.split(',');

splitSelectedDays.forEach(day => {
    let val = day.trim();

    if(val == 'Mon') {
        $('#mon').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('#mon').addClass('btn-primary');
    }

    if (val == 'Tue') {
        $('#tue').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('#tue').addClass('btn-primary');
    }

    if (val == 'Wed') {
        $('#wed').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('#wed').addClass('btn-primary');
    }

    if (val == 'Thur') {
        $('#thur').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('#thur').addClass('btn-primary');
    }

    if (val == 'Fri') {
        $('#fri').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('#fri').addClass('btn-primary');
    }

    if (val == 'Sat') {
        $('#sat').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('#sat').addClass('btn-primary');
    }

    if (val == 'Sun') {
        $('#sun').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('#sun').addClass('btn-primary');
    }
})
```

Console.Log of returned data
[image]

Comment: A tip: The argument to pass to `$` function is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technique you want to follow is called Don't Repeat Yourself, or DRY for short.

In this case the `day` is always the same as the `id` of the element you want to target, so you can manually build the selector string once from that. You can also use `toggleClass()` instead of alternate `addClass()` and `removeClass()` calls. Try this:

```
splitSelectedDays.forEach(day => {
  let dayName = day.trim().toLowerCase();
  $('#' + dayName).toggleClass('btn-default btn-primary');
})
```

Comment: This is almost therei think. i knew it moust have been able to be done just if i select a data row where one one day is available, it still highlights them all.  I have added a pic of the `DataTable` data

Comment: Sorry my bad i had one final `IF` i hadn't commented out foe if 'All Days' is returned which i missed a `=` out of so it was always falling in it. Superb answer thanks very much